# Frequency scaling

Tags: acpi, cpufreq

I'm trying to get the frequency of my CPU on max

I can't seem to change anything via cpupower or cpufreq-utils, or even by modifying the files myself at /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate

So I added inteal_pstate=disable to grub

Now I have no driver, I heard I have to load the acpi_cpufreq driver but I don't have it.

What do I do?

Comment: If you can not simply set performance mode with the intel_pstate driver, then you will have to give us more information about your system. And note that even in performance mode, the CPU frequency will not be locked at maximum. If the load is light enough the processor itself can back off the CPU frequency.

Comment: I have included some more information

Comment: I already know all that :( but frequency stays at 1.20GHz when it could up to 2.60GHz in theory. That's why I've disabled intel_pstate through grub but it still doesn't work

Comment: Is your computer a LapTop or? When frequency stays at 1.20GHz, is that after a suspend and when the intel_pstate driver is in performance mode? If yes, note that a patch was submitted for that scenario, and is included in [kernel 4.2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-unstable/), which you could try as a test.

Comment: no it's a server

Comment: see also https://serverfault.com/a/716347

Answer (score 3):

First of all, leave it disabled.

You do have a *"driver"* otherwise your computer wouldn't work. Run the following commands to install indicator-cpufreq:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

To start it up the first time, run the following command:

```
indicator-cpufreq &
```

It should start up automatically next reboot.

An icon will appear on your upper panel. Click on the icon to set the CPU frequency.

If you need to install acpi, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acpi-support acpid acpi
```

Or, if you just need cpufreq:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpufreqd cpufrequtils
```

---

**EDIT**

You need to disable pstate by editing `/etc/default/grub` and then you need to run `sudo update-grub` to update grub before you reboot in order to use the acpi driver.

Also, you should still be able to change the governor when you are using `intel_pstate` by running:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
```

or

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

Additionally, to list your current governor, run the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

To see available governors, run the following command:

cpupower frequency-info | grep "governors:"

Finally, to show real time frequency and additional information, you can install and use i7z.

To install i7z:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i7z
```

To run i7z:

```
sudo i7z
```

Comment: I should have say I have only a console. After installing `acpi` via your commands and doing a `cpupower frequency-info` I get `driver: intel_pstate` again and I still cannot change the frequency